# SSIS package only executes the last part of package in SQL Agent job but executes all of the package in Visual Studio

Tags: ssis

I created an SSIS package which has 3 script tasks that checks if a different file exists for each and if the any of the script tasks finds the file, then it goes to a foreach loop which imports data to a sql server staging table, then copy and renames the file.

It works successfully within Visual Studio, however when I set up a sql agent job, the package only processes the last file and ignores the first two.

Any ideas why this may be occurring?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit the [help] and read the [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Probably either permissions of the SQL Agent, or invalid file paths on the SQL Server.

Comment: All of the files have the same path and have the same permissions.  Only the last file executes in the agent job which is confusing.